# Does the velocity (or Drift Velocity) of an electron decrease after passing through a resistor?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Let's say a current is passed through a load (or more precisely, a source of resistance), then will the emerging electrons have less energy and less velocity with what they had entered the resistor?

Also, if the electrons emerge with a less velocity, won't there be an accumulation of them inside the resistor and thereby a violation of the KCL?

Answer (score 1):

Drift velocity is related to the current, the number of electrons passing by per second.

Imagine a crowded day at Disneyland. A huge mob of people are waiting to get on a ride. People are bored waiting and shuffle around a bit as they wait. A few people at one end get on the ride every so often. There is a bit of room, so people drift a bit in that direction.

The same thing happens at the other end. There is a huge mob leaving the ride, heading toward the exit. They shuffle around as they wait. Every so often a few people leave the ride. People drift away a bit to make room.

Suppose Disneyland put more cars in the ride so it could handle more people per hour. People would shuffle around the same, but would drift faster.

---

To see how energy comes into it, consider that electrons repel each other. If you push extra electrons onto one end of a wire, they are crowded closer together. The electrons gain potential energy. They spread out evenly so the crowding is uniform.

This this change in average spacing is very small in a circuit. More crowded electrons means a negative charge. This charge is present, but so small that it isn't noticeable.

In Disneyland terms, people are grumpy about the wait. They push and shove. This makes it hard for people arriving at the entrance to get in. Disneyland handles this by having attendants push people in. It increases the crowding inside.

At the exit, there is nothing holding people inside. People can't see where the exit is. They just push and shove and drift until they arrive at the exit. The crowding is slightly less on this side.

The number of people leaving per second is the same as the number of people arriving. The drift speed is pretty much the same.

A change in crowding would make a difference in drift speed. But the change in crowding is so small that it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

An important condition to remember is that in an electrical circuit, all electrons travel in a closed loop. With a potential difference, current will flow in the loop at the same drift velocity. Adding a resistor slows the entire electron queue since the electrons are traveling in a loop and the velocity of each electron depends on the velocity of the electron ahead of it in the queue. If the electrons did not travel in a loop then electrons could resume velocity after passing through the resistor and your visualization about  electron accumulation would be true.

The turnstile analogy that mmesser314 used is excellent. Imagine a people arranged in a circle. The circumference of the circle contains people lined from front to back and packed as tightly as possible but still allowing people to move. Now imagine them running as fast as possible in the circle. The velocity of people in the circle will be the same and the velocity will be limited by the slowest person in the queue. Adding a turnstile, will change the velocity equally for all in the queue since they are already packed as closely as possible. No accumulation of people.